# Fetching the html from view in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I have created an action index which is giving a complete HTML

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:index.html.twig');  
}
```

This is a dynamic form builder for which when I click on text field button then a text field is generated and accordingly the html is changed. Now I want to get this new html in another action

```
public function subAction(Request $request)
{
    $this->container->get('templating')
        ->renderResponse('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
}
```

When I am using this thing then it is only rendering the older html, but I need the new generated html. How can i render this?

Comment: Can't understand your questions, you need to more specific

Comment: Please, add more examples with logic implementation, controllers, form rendering and so on

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701396/generate-dynamic-html-in-symfony2

Comment: @drupality I want to get the complete HTML of one view and want to use it in another view file

Comment: @umpirsky that link is also by me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get complete HTML of one view in another, you can use [include](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html).

If you want to embed entire action output, you can use [render](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_view.html#embedding-other-controllers).

Comment: actually when i am using render then it is fetching only the html which is defined already. I have used javascript in it which is adding some text into the innerHTML. now i want to fetch the html of this edited file.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Please try to explain it better, maybe share some gist or any public link to your code or some of key parts and give me a ping.

Comment: yeah i got a live link. if we see the website              http://bootstrap-forms.heroku.com/ it is generating the forms dynamically.when i clik on any link then the innerHTML of the blok in the form name on the left side. In the first twig file I want to show the complete this view. but in another view I want to show only the part which is in `form name` block.

Comment: OK, make one twig view for the part which is in form name block, and another one for entire page where you can include the first one. BTW, where is your source code? Gimme github link.